# Using OAuth dialog for facebook app do not allow to use canvas URL as redirect_uri

Tags: dialog, facebook-apps

I am starting a Facebook app. Following the [Getting Started tutorial in the Authorization section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth), it says I should use this URL to get permission from users:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE
```

I am replacing YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE with my canvas URL, the one I see on my app settings:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F238620302882463%2F
```

But, then, if I navigate to that page, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred with Elecciones 2012. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

If I replace YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE with:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FElecciones2012
```

The permission dialog works fine. But then I get redirected to my website, not the app inside facebook.com

Any idea why is this happening??

I have seen other apps using a different permission dialogue:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=11609831134&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fpetsociety%2F%3Fpf_ref%3Dsb%26ref%3Dts&response_type=none&display=page&perms=email%2Cpublish_actions&auth_referral=1
```

But it looks it is part of another set of APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too. Looks like the problem is in "Canvas URL". You cannot use your app id in canvas URL like:

> "https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F238620302882463%2F"

Instead, the namespace should be used as your canvas URL. for example:

> "https://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/"

You can set your app namespace in the application settings in facebook.