# OAuth facebook pagetab app error

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm totally stuck on this one..
I cant get js sdk or even the oauth link working..
When I try the oauth example, it works just fine:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/&response_type=token

but in my case:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=317872318261965&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FDigiComm%2F185749568187479%3Fsk%3Dapp_317872318261965&response_type=token

the link is basically the same, but get's an error
I've been fighting with this for days.. And can't understand, what could be the problem,
because each time i try to open the auth dialog with js sdk i get this same error..
It must be an error in the app settings on facebook side, but i cant understand what..

I'd say i have the same problem as this guy..
but as i can see he hasnt gotten any answer too:
[Using OAuth dialog for facebook app do not allow to use canvas URL as redirect_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030197/using-oauth-dialog-for-facebook-app-do-not-allow-to-use-canvas-url-as-redirect-u)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the canvas/tab/website URL's in the developer app ([https://developers.facebook.com/apps/317872318261965](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/31787231826196)) match the redirect URI in your url.

At the moment, your link is pointing to http://www.example.com - you need to point this to wherever your app is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

try to add http://www.example.com/ with all the slashes as website and example.com as app domain

Update:

If it is a canvas app your redirect_uri should be:

```
urlencode("http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAMESPACE/");
```

Comment: Thank's
that's what i did before. but it isn't really what i wanted.. because now it is opening the page as it was website..
please compare the links now. as you can see. what i wanted to achieve was to get permissions request like the first one

Comment: you never said it should be facebook app. :) Is it canvas or page app? The first one is getting permissions for website.

Comment: Yes it should be canvas app..
how do i open a dialog like canvas app?

Comment: I already tried that before.
That still doesnt solve the problem with how the prompt for permissions are formed..
I mean please compare what happens if you open both links..
as you can see the permission prompts differ

Comment: huh?!? you had a problem with error on getting permission.... and I answered that.

Comment: Sorry for that..
Well it's just that i really need to achieve a prompt like the first one.. but the same link works different for me..
please have a look..
how do I make a prompt like the first link has..

Comment: Disable Enchanced Auth Dialog in app settings.

Comment: FINALLY!
Thank you very much!
I knew it would have to be something simple that i just cant fund!
thank's a million!

Comment: Glad I could help. Just acccept the answer now :P